# How to dynamically set focus back to element in valueChanges subscription callback?

Tags: angular, focus

I have the following code to create a new FormControl.

When I update the `FormControl` by clicking ("blurring") away, everything is fine, but if I hit `Enter` then the input element wildly loses focus and I get taken to a far-away corner of my form.

So I want to make sure that in the `valueChanges` callback, I imperatively set focus back to the element (after `renderArrayData()`).

Is this possible?

```
this.formCtls[controlName] = new FormControl(value, {updateOn: 'blur'});
this.userForm.addControl(controlName, this.formCtls[controlName]);
this.formCtls[controlName].valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
   itm["value"][itm["attr"]["active"][i]]=val;
   if (itm["enum"]) this.userForm.patchValue({controlName: val}); 
   this.renderDataArray();
});
```

Comment: Can you post both html and .ts code so that we can reproduce the issue on our end?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

For the html add the reference attribute as

```
<input #inputtofocus >
```

```
//declare the map as Element Ref

@ViewChild('inputtofocus') inputele  ElementRef;


//To focus use after your render data array function

this.inputele.nativeElement.focus()
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. My problems are: 1. I have multiple, dynamically-generated inputs, so I think I need a custom directive rather than using `#inputtofocus`. 2. Because of the multiple inputs, I will need to use `ViewChildren`, 3. WIth `ViewChildren` it seems that the result of the `QueryList` query only becomes available (is only defined/usable) in `ngAfterViewInit`, but (I think) I need to use this in `ngOnInit`. I'm working through these issues now, but if you have any further guidance in the meantime, that will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you all for your input. As I still have a lot of questions, I posted a new question to <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58253058/how-to-get-specific-item-in-viewchildren-querylist-as-elementref-while-filtering> and that question includes a StackBlitz link so that people can see the full model/data, etc.