# How to get specific item in ViewChildren QueryList as ElementRef while filtering on property(ies)?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set focus to any given input after that input changes (or potentially manipulate that same DOM element in other ways). I'm using Reactive Forms and the Form elements are rendered dynamically.

The problem I have is that I can access the element that has been changed using either `@ViewChildren(AppTag) ipt!: QueryList<AppTag>` which lets me filter on the element I want, but then I don't know how to grab that element using `nativeElement`, or I can use `@ViewChildren(AppTag) ipt!: QueryList<ElementRef>`, which (surprisingly) seems to be letting me filter the element in question, but (also surprisingly) I'm still unable to manipulate the DOM element. Either way, I get error: `"itm.nativeElement is undefined"`.

To reproduce the error, please enter any value into one of the `Inputs` in the following  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghxtvh), and then `TAB` out of the entry. You'll see the error in the console.

Below are what I think are the relevant pieces of code, but please play around with the full StackBlitz example to see the template and data structure more clearly:

`app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChildren(AppTag) ipt !: QueryList<ElementRef>
  name = 'Angular';
  formCtls: any = {};
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  data: {} = { // raw data
    name: 
    {
      first: {values: [""], label: "first name"},
      middle: {values: [""], label: "middle name"},
      last: {values: [""], label: "last name"}
    } 
  };
  dispData: any[] = []; // Data formatted for display/iteration by template
  itmNo: number = 0; // Unique ID for each Input
  focusItm = 0; // The bridge by which "FormControl.valueChanges" communicates with "QueryList.changes"

. . . 
. . .

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ipt.changes.subscribe(list=>{
      setTimeout(()=>
        list.filter(itm=>+itm.id===this.focusItm).forEach(itm=>{
          console.log(`Item: ${itm.id} Focus: ${this.focusItm} ${+itm.id===this.focusItm}`);
          itm.nativeElement.focus();  // <-- HERE'S WHERE I'M HAVING THE TROUBLE
        }  
    ),0)}
    )
  }

. . . 
. . .


  renderDisplayArray(){
    this.dispData = [];
    this.itmNo = 0;

. . . 
. . .

          const i=r;
          this.formCtls[ctlName] = new FormControl(itm["values"][r], {updateOn: 'blur'});
          this.form.addControl(ctlName,this.formCtls[ctlName]);
          const curItm=this.itmNo;

          this.formCtls[ctlName].valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
            console.log(`VALUE: ${val}`);
            itm["values"][i]=val || '';
            this.renderDisplayArray();
            this.focusItm = curItm;

          })
. . . 
. . .
```

Here's the Directive `AppTag` which I apply to the Inputs to be able to `filter` and grab the DOM elements I want. 
appTag.ts

```
import { Component, Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTag]'
})

export class AppTag implements OnInit{

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
@Input('appTag') id: number;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the visibility from `el: ElementRef` in `AppTag` to public

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTag]'
})
export class AppTag implements OnInit{
   constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}
   @Input('appTag') id: number;
}
```

and use in your filter function the `el` property of the `AppTag`.

Change your problem line to this:

```
itm.el.nativeElement.focus();  // <-- HERE'S WHERE I'M HAVING THE TROUBLE
```

Comment: By the way, I looked, but couldn't find out what does the "!" mean in `@ViewChildren(AppTag) ipt !: QueryList<ElementRef>`. Does anyone know?

Comment: @Crowdpleasr That is a non null assertion operator. Its a way to say to the compiler that you as developer knows very well that this value can't be null.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#type-widening

Comment: Thank you, and much appreciated!